# How to Create Dynamic Form in React from following Json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Please give me an Idea how to use map() for below json and how to create dynamic form for this json.
I m not getting how to use this json for create dynamic from in react-native

```
{
    "Location": {
        "field_count": 1,
        "field_name": [
            "location"
        ],
        "field_type": "TextField",
        "context_type": "Location",
        "field_unit": null,
        "is_compulsory": true
    },
    "Maximum Tie Bar": {
        "field_count": 2,
        "field_name": [
            "max_tie_bar_1",
            "max_tie_bar_2"
        ],
        "field_type": "TextField",
        "context_type": "Decimal",
        "field_unit": "mm x mm",
        "is_compulsory": true
    },
    "Type": {
        "field_count": 1,
        "field_name": [
            "type"
        ],
        "field_type": "Dropdown",
        "field_values": [
            "Injection Mold",
            "Gas Injection Mold",
            "PVC Mold",
            "Overmold/Insert Mold",
            "Transfer Mold",
            "Compression Mold",
            "2k Mold",
            "Stack Mold"
        ],
        "is_compulsory": true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you try something? What's blocking you from doing a .map with a switch case or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:
First Loop over your JSON object

```
Object.keys(JSON_OBJECT).map(function(item) {
  renderItemsFromJson(JSON_OBJECT[item])
});
```

Conditionally render your items accordingly

```
renderItemsFromJson = (item) => {
    switch(item.field_type){
        case 'TextField':
            return '<TextInput>[Inside code]</TextInput>'
        case 'Dropdown':
           return '<YourDropDownComponent>[Insidecode]</YourDropDownComponent>'
        //Likewise
    }
}
```